# Select object by clicking it (not based on origin)

Tags: selection-tools

I have a very annoying issue, I have set left click select. The problem is that when I try to select an object Blender will not only choose the object based on the origin that is the closest 90% of the time but it also selects more than 1 sometimes. I want to select what I click on regardless of which origin is nearby. I can't find any options for this.

Answer (score 1):

Use Alt+click to choose which object to select in the menu listing all objects underneath your mouse position, even if their origin is far from the zone.

[image]